# protobuf-net Stream is disposed before returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ado.net, protobuf-net, sqlclient

I have a webapi that returns some protobuf-net serialized items after being transformed from a database column. The number of items can be rather large so I'd like to avoid materializing them all in memory and rather stream them out however, I never get a single one out before my Stream throws an already disposed exception. If I materialize the list it does work but I'd like to avoid it.
Here is what I'm doing::

```
private override async Task<IEnumerable<MyObj>> GetRawData(int id)
{
    using(var sqlConn = GetOpenConnection())
    {
        using (var sqlReader =(await sqlConn.ExecuteReaderAsync(
            _workingQuery,new {id = id}, 60)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false) as SqlDataReader))
        {
            await sqlReader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            using (var stream = sqlReader.GetStream(0))
            {
               return _serializerModel.DeserializeItems<MyObj>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1)
            }                
        }
    }
}

private async Task<IHttpActionResult> TransformData(int id)
{   
    var data=await GetRawData().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Ok(new {Data=data.Where(m=>...).Select(m=>...)})
}
[HttpGet,Route("api/myroute/{id}"]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetObjs(int id)
{
     return await TransformData();
}
```

However, I end getting an error about reading a disposed stream. How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Show your serializerModel class.

Comment: It's a protobuf-net typemodel object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long and short of it is that you are returning a non-enumerated sequence, and closing (disposing) everything it needs before it ever gets to the caller. You're going to need to either:

- enumerate the sequence eagerly (buffer in memory) - for example, adding `.ToList()`
- restructure the code so that nothing is disposed until the *end* of the iteration

For the latter, I would be tempted to use an iterator block for the central part (after all the `await`). Something like:

```
bool dispose = true;
SqlConnection conn = null;
//...others
try {
   conn = ...
   ...await...
   var result = InnerMethod(conn, stream, ..., ) 
    // ^^^ everything now known / obtained from DB
    dispose = false; // handing lifetime management to the inner method
    return result;
} finally {
    if(dispose) {
        using(conn) {}
        //.//
    }
}

IEnumerable<...> Inner(...) { // not async
    using (conn)
    using (stream) {
         foreach(var item in ...) {
             yield return item;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks marc. I ended up doing a very similar approach. I'm curious as to why returning a function that calls yield return iterator block allowed this all to work where as returning the also lazy lazy iterator of `DeserializeItems` caused it to dispose immediately. Is it because I tied the disposal of the resource to the end of the iteration?

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
return _serializerModel.DeserializeItems<MyObj>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1)
```

Returns just an **indexer**. As you seem to be aware the result is not yet materialized. However, right after the return, the `using` block disposes your `Stream`.

The solution would be to have `GetRawData` return the **Stream**. Then, inside `TransformData`, inside a `using` block for the `Stream`, you deserialize, filter and return the results.

The second potential issue is that your current approach processes the whole result and then sends it to the client all at once.

In order to have **Web API** send a streamed result you need to use `HttpResponseMessage`, and pass a `Stream` to it's `Content` property.

Here's an example: http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi

When you want to stream a `Stream` to another `Stream` (I know, it sounds funny), you need to keep the `ReaderStream` open until the `WriterStream` is done writing. This is a high level representation:

```
using (ReaderStream)
{
    using (WriterStream)
    {
        // write object from ReaderStream to WriterStream
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so as the Where and Select are lazy operators that don't materialize the Enumerable. The objects will be materialized but once written to the json stream, they are candidates to be thrown away. If I write them to a list, I pay the cost of materialization right then and there, and then I can only throw away the objects after they are all written to the stream.

Comment: After further investigation I agree with your first statement. However the second is not true. new {Data=...} materializes the whole Json object and then sends it. In order to stream the results you need to have Web API return a stream.

Comment: The problem still remains with ultimately not disposing of the stream,reader, or connection object while the stream is being read.  I can sort of trick this out but I don't want the controller disposing of the connection.As `GetRawData` should own it and just disposing the stream doesn't dispose the connection . The push content stream is an interesting idea.

Comment: Using the approach that I'm suggesting in the second half of my answer, you can have a separate function reading the ReaderStream and returning the WriterStream to the response. The controller will still be responsible for closing the WriterStream, which on it's closure will also close the ReaderStream but there's not much to do about that.